# Add a class to a div if custom post type has specific terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

For example: if the post has the terms 'movies' or 'tv' I would like to add a class of "on" to a div in the post.

```
<div class="box [added class here]"
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? :) It sounds like you need to create a child theme and add logic to whichever template you are trying to affect, which is likely `single.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure something out. I created a function and added it to the class name of the div. Probably more work, but it got the job done.

```
function add_class() {
    if( has_term( 'movies', 'genre' ) ) {
        echo 'on';
    }
}
add_filter('add_class_on', 'add_class');
```

then add function to div class

```
<div class="box <?php add_class();?>"</div>
```

Comment: You don't need the add_filter() line I don't think. (That's not a filter function anyway: filters should accept at least one argument and return a value, often the first argument unchanged.)